# How to train a chess system with games played by humans (Machine Learning in Chess)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

As a part of my project, I'm now working on training a chess system with games played by humans. I have significant knowledge on machine learning but am clueless on how to proceed with this. Is this project too complex? Kindly advise on how to proceed.

Comment: It is indeed quite a complex project. The best chess engines are just blind number crunchers, evaluating all possibilities for the next X turns. And they take shortcuts and are optimised something crazy… But rarely is it any sort of ANN. In your project though, try to separate all of the games in your database into individual turns, and use that to train the ANN. Try a score of some sort to sort different turns for the same position? Maybe provide the score along with the training data?

Comment: If you ask such question then there is nearly 100% chance that this is too complex task for you for now. ML based game playing is not a good starting point for learning anything; it currently involves many advanced techniques like reinforcment learning, monte carlo methods, uct, deep architectures etc.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how many training samples (moves/full matches) do you have?

Comment: @BlackBear Around 5 million games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want is a ML system which plays chess?

One way to get it, is to see it as a pattern recognition problem. If you modeled it with a neural network, you could approach it like this:

- the input is a binary vector of size 768=64*2*6  (64=8*8 positions on the board, 2 Players, 6 different chess figures)
- 64 output neurons (one for each field).
- The network would give you a clue which piece to move. It tries to **predict which piece a human player would choose**. If the network chooses something invalid, you can just go to the next most likely piece (assuming you make use of softmax at the end).

You could train a second network which takes the same input. You might think about building a CNN with 12 feature maps instead of a MLP. This network should **predict which player will win**. Then you know which figure would be moved by a human with the first network and then you can find the "best" move with the second network.

### More resources

You might be interested in [Better Computer Go Player with Neural Network and Long-term Prediction](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06410) by Facebook Research.